# How do I write something directly inside the circle?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, debugging

I would like to write something directly inside the circle but I'm not sure how to.  I know I could just write `ctx.fillText("     test", 10, 30);` and it would move to the right but I feel like that's an inefficient way of doing it.

How would I achieve this?  Below is an image of what I'm referring to.

[image]

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Login extends Component {    
    componentDidMount() {
        let c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        let ctx = c.getContext("2d");

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(100,75,50,0,2*Math.PI);
        ctx.fillText("hey", 10, 30);
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <canvas id="myCanvas" width="240" height="200"/>
            </div>    
        );
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `measureText` to get the width of the your text and calculate coordinate for starting point for the text:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    let c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    let ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    const x_arc = 100;
    const y_arc = 75;
    const radius = 50;

    const text = "hey";
    const text_width = ctx.measureText(text).width;
    const x_text = x_arc - text_width / 2;
    const y_text = y_arc;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x_arc, y_arc, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillText("hey", x_text, y_text);
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="240" height="200" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here the link to sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/j377qol3ww

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you do the math:

```
the x of the circle is: 100
the y of the circle is: 75
So, the text should be around (95, 80)
```

Note: the (x, y) coordinate of the `text` is dependent on the one of the circle. That's been said, you can make it more dynamic:

```
const circleCords = { x: 100, y: 75 }

// You can adjust the x, y of the text. Because `5` is just for testing. 
// I mean by that, that you would have to get the width of the text and then calculate how much you'd subtract from the circleCords!
const textCords = { x: circleCords - 5, y: circleCords + 5 }

ctx.arc(circleCords.x, circleCords.y, 50, 0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.fillText("hey", textCords.x, textCords.y);
```

> If your text's width is always constant, you'll be fine by subtracting random number as desired. In this case `5`.

Hope that could help!

Comment: ah ok but how did you derive 95, 80 from 100, 75 by doing the math?  Also, I tried this and tried changing up coords but I can't see `test` at all.